# is there any plugin to use git on gedit on ubuntu?

Tags: git, gedit

i would like to use a git plugin while coding on gedit. i mean by that buttons for commit or shortcuts.
thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I created one that is fully integrated and supports SVN as well as GIT. Even has a little repo viewer. Let me know if you have any trouble with it:

http://gombi.net/#showcase/giterdone

Comment: The link seems to be broken :(

Comment: The link worked but after pasting the folder in several places it does nto show up in the plugin list. Using gedit 2.30.3

Comment: URL is updated to: http://gombi.net/#showcase/giterdone, waiting for the peer to review the edit. But Plugin is not working.

Answer (score 2):

I just used the external tools plugin, very trivial to set it up to run gitk

```
#!/bin/sh
exec gitk $GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_PATH
```

for git add

```
#!/bin/sh
exec git add $GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_PATH
```

etc

Answer (score 1):

I just came across http://github.com/rafaelmws/git-gedit yesterday, but I've yet to try it out.

There's also http://code.google.com/p/gedit-vcs/, which appears to have never made it past the requirements stage.

Comment: i just found something called rabbitVCS, that looks cool.I am trying to make it work but there are no tutorials about it online.

Answer (score 0):

I found this nice little thing: http://nerdblog.pl/2009/06/01/save-and-commit-to-git-plugin-for-gedit-2-26ave/

Comment: Aw, that sucks. Most plugins broke from Gedit 2 to Gedit 3 anyways. :(